# pdb file is mising after PostSharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, postsharp, pdb-files

I am using PostSharp version 2.1.6.4 (also tried latest version 2.1.7.35) and sometimes pdb file is missing and there is a pssym file in it's place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Symbols xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/2.0/symbols">
  <Class Class="#1=T:[CrosscuttingLogging]CrosscuttingLogging.Attributes.LogMethodCallStatsAttribute" LimitedLicense="true" />
  <Class Class="#2=T:[RequestLimiter]RequestLimiter.RequestCounterAttribute" LimitedLicense="true" />
</Symbols>
```

I ran procmon on the build process and as far as I can tell the `postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe` process moves both dll and pdb files from `obj\Debug` folder to `obj\Debug\Before-PostSharp` folder and later on generates a new dll in `obj\Debug` folder, but *a new pdb file is **not** generated*.

This happens for some of my dlls (seemingly at random) and does not seem to be reliable, because on other machine all pdb files are generated correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PostSharp 2.1.x doesn't support Visual Studio 2015 (.NET4.6/Roslyn).

The PDB format has changed a little bit in .NET 4.6. I would expect that there is an exception in PostSharp during PDB post-processing which is the reason why the PDB is not copied to the output folder. If you are using VS2015, then this kind of issues could happen.

The solution is either not to use .NET4.6/Roslyn with PostSharp 2.x or to upgrade to at least PostSharp 3.1.

Comment: Still had this issue with PostSharp 3.1; upgraded to the latest release (which is 4.1.x) which fixed the issue. In my case, it´s a .NET 4.5 solution which I migrated to Visual Studio 2015... I am not using .NET 4.6 yet.

Comment: i have postsharp 4.2 and still getting this. Unknown custom metadata item kind: 6.

Comment: Which 4.2 version do you use? Are both PostSharp nuget package and PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio on 4.2 version?

Comment: We have the same problem with VS2015 update 3, .NET 4.5.2 and Postsharp 2.1. (VS2015 Update 1 works)

Comment: It's not a problem of 4.6. The issue takes place for any target framework in all VS starting 2015. So if your project had PostSharp 2.x then you (as me) have to stick to VS2013 forever. This is terrible. And this is why I won't use PostSharp again ever.

Comment: This case is explained at  http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/3849-postsharp-2x-and-vs20152017.

Comment: The issue is even occurring in PostSharp v5.0.44 on Visual Studio 2017 (v15.7.3)

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and I upgraded from PostSharp 3.1.46 to 3.1.67 and it did resolve my case. I do get the .pdb file created and I am able to debug again.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, same workaround. Upgraded from 3.1.51 to 3.1.69 and pdb generated again.