# No pdb generated in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I've got a solution that works fine when I open it in VS2013 (Ultimate), but when I open it in VS2015 (Enterprise), two of the projects don't generate debug information.

One project is an MVC 5 app and the other is a class library. All projects in the solution are set to .net 4.5 and all are set to debug mode

The advanced settings for both projects are set to full and appear to compile without issue, yet when I open the Debug > Windows > Modules window while the site is running, these two binaries have "Binary was not built with debug information" in their Symbol Status (every other binary in the solution loads symbols correctly)

I've deleted the bin/obj folders, cleared temporary asp.net files, restarted both VS and windows(10) and no luck

This is affecting other team members, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with my environment

Also, if I compile in VS2013, VS2015 will use the pdb's without problem, it just won't generate them for itself

I'm assuming this is a setting/feature/bug somewhere in VS2015, but i'm not sure what else I can check/change to get this sorted out

EDIT: The web project has it's web.config set to debug="true" and it isn't being affected by config transforms

Comment: is the configuration set to debug? If not, set it to 'Debug' and not release. Then Delete all builds and build again.

Comment: Forgot to mention i'd already checked this - updated the question

Comment: I didn't find any option on UI therefore I opened the csproj file in notepad and found <DebugType>none</DebugType>. So, I changed it to 'full' by comparing it with another temp project.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It turns out that this was a problem with PostSharp

The projects both referenced version 3.1.52 - after upgrading to 4.1.21 we now have pdb's being generated again

I'm not quite sure what the issue is or why it's manifested this way, but hopefully this might stop someone else banging their head against the wall like i've been!

Comment: Cheers. Ran into the same issue. I like PostSharp, but I'm starting to wonder whether it's more pain than it's worth..

Comment: me too. PostSharp is real pain sometimes.

Comment: This is frustrating.  Looking forward to ripping PostSharp out of my solution.

Comment: I had the same problem. Turns out my project was pointing to the compiled version in the GAC.  I removed that reference and re-added the nuget package.

Comment: see this for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057970/pdb-file-is-mising-after-postsharp

Answer (score 14):

Same problem occurs if old version of **Telerik open data access** is used in the project. Project generates pdp file when build through VS2013 but doesn't do the same when build using VS2015.

It was painfull and time taking to find out the reason that it requires latest version Q2 (which doesn't have Visual designer - version Q1 2015 of Telerik Data Access is the last one that distributes Visual Studio integration and code generation features)

Anyway read the Telerik support blog http://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-2015-ctp6-does-not-generate-pdb-file

Comment: Thank you... and yes painful is an understatement and a huge loss of the Visual Designer.

Answer (score 11):

Actually debug has nothing to do with if pdb's are generate or not. Lot of people generates pdb's for production releases and keep them in a local symbol store. 
Anyways try to go to the build tab under the project and then Advanced and set debug info to pdb-only or full.

Comment: both projects already have their advanced debug info set to full

Comment: are you using any telerik products? seems like they have that issue.. http://www.telerik.com/forums/visual-studio-2015-ctp6-does-not-generate-pdb-file

Comment: This is really odd... you could try to open a csproj that generates pdb and only that don't and compare them in a texteditor, maybe you will be able to spot someting...

Comment: there is also the possibility to create a new project and import all the code, but that seems a bit hackish and might not even work.

Comment: Thanks - your comment about the telerik stuff got me thing about what we were using that could be interfering with the process

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually add `<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>` in the *.csproj file to the PropertyGroup with matching condition to the build configuration I was debugging with.