# .PDB file not getting generated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I have a project which I need to debug in another solution. I'm trying to generate a PDB file, but its not getting generated. However, a .PSSYM file is getting generated.
Things that I have already tried:

- Set the Configuration to Debug
- Set Build > Advanced > Debug Info > FULL
- Clean and Rebuild
- Restart Visual studio
- Rename the PSSYM to PDB extension

Why is it not getting generated? And what is this PSSYM file?

Comment: .pssym is generated probably you have post sharp running post build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdb file is mising after PostSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057970/pdb-file-is-mising-after-postsharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, Postsharp was messing with it, even after updating it.
I set the Conditional Compilation Symbols to "SkipPostSharp" for my project and my PDB got generated.

Answer (score 12):

Under **Build** > **Advanced** > **Debug Info**, change **Debugging Info** to **PDB-Only**.

This will generate a PDB file for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the csproj file of the project you want to debug and make sure the following line is there.

```
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
```

Note 'pdbonly'